# Setting the currentTime of an <audio> tag not working?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have this audio tag playing in the background, and I'm able to store the progress in seconds to a cookie.
But in no way I'm able to start the audio from that cookie. (for continuing on other pages)

```
$("p#sound audio").currentTime = $.cookie("audioTime");

<audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime); $.cookie('audioTime', Math.floor(this.currentTime));">
    <source src="audio/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="audio/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
<span id="tracktime">0</span>
```

Does this have to do with the song being loaded again from start?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
$("p#sound audio").get[0].currentTime
```

With .get[0], it doesn't work either.

Can someone please clear things up for me? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same sort of issue. I've made sure the audio is loaded, via binding a callback to the `canplay` event as mentioned by Brian Hadaway. Even with this, `currentTime` will not change.

Comment: Also having this problem. No idea where to go with my debugging. Everything appears to be correct but currentTime just will not set...

Answer (score 10):

You need to wait until `audio` source loads before you set the current time.

```
$(function(){
    $('audio').bind('canplay', function(){
        $(this)[0].currentTime = $.cookie('audioTime');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the start time by adding `t=<time>` to the URL, as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range

E.g. `<audio src="http://example.com/audio.mp3#t=50></audio>`

Answer (score 3):

At first there is an error in your code because currentTime is not a part of jQuery (but you already know this)

```
$("p#sound audio").currentTime // is incorrect (refers to a property of jQuery)
$("p#sound audio")[0].currentTime // is correct (refers to a property of DOM element)
```

I discover that the audio tag has some strange things and can be operate differently from browser to browser, for example in Chrome.

At first you have to wait for the '`durationchange`' event to be sure the length is known by the object.

After this you have to start the stream with '`play()`' (if not already started) and pause it (sometimes after a short delay) with the '`pause()`' function. Then you can change the 'currentTime' property with the value. After this you have to start the stream again by using the `'play()`' function.

Also it is sometimes needed to load the stream by yourself by using the '`load()`' function.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
var a = $('audio:first'),
    o = a[0];

a.on( 'durationchange', function(e)
{
  var o = e.target;
  if( o )
  {
   o.pause();
   o.currentTime = parseInt( $.cookie("audioTime"));
   o.play();
  } 
});

if( o )
{
  o.load();
  o.play();
}
});
```

You have to play with it to be sure what is the best in your situation, for example the resume (play again) method to delay it for a second or so.

When using this method you don't have to use the autoplay feature because most of the time it doesn't work.

Hope it helps, greetz,
Erwinus

Comment: This didn't fix my problem but +1 for trying and illustrating how poor the support for sounds in HTML is.

Answer (score 1):

what I found in my case is that there is an issue with context somewhere. I initialize audio under the window context but when I try to change currentTime from XMLHttpRequest response it does NOT work. I don't know the answer yet but I'm providing a clue maybe an expert in Javascript will know how to make it work.

```
/* initialize this.audio player */
Audio = function() {
    var that = this;
    // keep track of playback status
    var AudioStatus = {
            isPlaying : false
    };

    // define references to this.audio, pulldown menu, play-button, slider and time display
    that.audio = document.querySelector("AUDIO");

    /* load track by menu-index */
    var loadTrack = function() {

        if(that.audio == null){
            log("audio null"); return;
        }
        that.audio.src = '../sounds/400.mp3';
        that.audio.load();
    };

    /* callback to play or pause */
    that._play = function() {
        if(that.audio == null){
            log("audio null"); return;
        }  
        that.audio.play();
        AudioStatus.isPlaying = true;
    };

    that._pause = function() {

        if(that.audio == null){
            log("audio null"); return;
        }
        that.audio.pause();
        AudioStatus.isPlaying = false;
    };

    that.playPause = function() {
        if (that.audio.paused) {
            self._play();
        }
        else {
            self._pause();
        }
    };

    /* callback to set or update playback position */
    that.updateProgress = function(value) {
        if(that.audio == null){
            log("audio null"); return;
        }
        that.audio.currentTime = value;    // <<<--- it does NOT work if I call from XMLHttpRequest response but it DOES if it is called from a timer expired call back
    };

    that.isAudioPlaying = function(){
        return AudioStatus.isPlaying;
    };
};
```

Comment: At the first line observation of your code I see you assign a function (non-protyped user class) to the HTML5 Audio class definition. Audio is a part of the HTML5 API, don't try to use these words. Audio is the Javascript version of the audio tag in HTML. If you want to create a class use for example a name like theAudio instead to avoid API conflicts. Also your query selector might be wrong, AUDIO must be audio. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
if (!isNaN(audio.duration)) {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

```js
  $("p#sound audio").on('loadedmetadata', () => {
    $("p#sound audio").get(0).load();
  });
```

So I could later set the `currentTime` without worrying about whether the audio was loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to play a HLS stream through an HTML audio element.

No matter where and how I tried to set the currentTime property on the audio element, it wouldn't work until about 2.5s after calling audioElement.play().

```
//Calling this
htmlElement.currentTime = 5.5;
console.log('currentTime: '+htmlElement.currentTime);
//Would return 'currentTime: 0';
```

What did work tho, was if I called that in a timeout with 2500-3000ms delay.
After a day of debugging to pinpoint the element state in which it would allow me to set the currentTime property, so I wouldn't have to rely on a fixed timeout.

My solution was to listen to 3 HTMLMediaElement events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events): **loadedmetadata**, **loadeddata** and **canplaythrough** and setting custom flags when they were first reported.
When all 3 were reported and the HTMLMediaElement.duration property was bigger than 0, I set the HTMLMediaElement.currentTime to my desired value inside the first HTMLMediaElement **timeupdate** event callback.

This can be summed up in the following code snippet:

```
let audioElementStates = {
    'metadataloaded': false,
    'dataloaded': false,
    'canplaythrough': false
};
let shouldSetOldTime = true;
let audioElement = document.getById('audio-element');
audioElement.src = 'https://somedomain.com/hlsplaylist.m3u8';

audioElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',()=>{audioElementStates.metadataloaded = true;});
audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata',()=>{audioElementStates.dataloaded = true;});
audioElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough',()=>{audioElementStates.canplaythrough = true;});
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>{
    if(shouldSetOldTime && 
          audioElement.duration>0 &&
          audioElementStates.metadataloaded &&
          audioElementStates.dataloaded &&
          audioElementStates.canplaythrough){
         audioElement.currentTime = 5.5;
         shouldSetOldTime=false;
    }
});


audioElement.play();
```

For reference I was using this with Vue.js in a Quasar framework mobile app packaged with Apache Cordova.

**NOTE:** The **loadedmetadata** check can probably be skipped, since **loadeddata** would presumably never fire before **loadedmetadata**.