# Can't set currentTime for audio in javascript (only IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-audio

I want to create a script that allow user start play audio from 20nd seconds, it work well on all browser and device, except on IOS.
Here is the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var audio = new Audio();

    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click',function(){
        audio.src = "test.mp3";
        audio.play();
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 20;
        audio.play();
        alert(audio.currentTime);
    });
});
```

When debugged, on IOS browser, such as chrome on iphone, the alert value was 0 second, other cases return 20. The audio was played normally.
Which points am I wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are not trying to call this before the audio element has loaded.

Here is a nice article explaining some bugs on iOS.

[iOS Audio Bug Workarounds](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/)

It’s an older article but a lot of the same problems still exist on iOS.

Read this stackoverflow post for a series of good answers

[Stackoverflow audio solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621511/setting-the-currenttime-of-an-audio-tag-not-working)

Comment: Okay, so sad, it was IOS problem, can't do anything, if I use loadmetadata event, it will make a bit delay on play time

Comment: iOS tends to screw with you like that a lot:/